# InferSchema using spark.read.table().toPandas()

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm having an issue: `Possible cause: Parquet column cannot be converted` while reading a table on Databricks using `spark.read.table().toPandas()`

I read that I could use inferSchema, but I don't know how to use it with `spark.read.table()`. I've found nothing regarding `spark.read.table()` only `.csv`.

Another thing I've tried is the command `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader","false")` at the notebook as recommend [here](https://kb.databricks.com/scala/spark-job-fail-parquet-column-convert.html). But it didn't worked.

Comment: what is the schema of your df when reading normally the table ?

Comment: LongType, and it is finding DOUBLE

Comment: I'm asking you the output of `spark.read.table().printSchema()`